# ggplot2 - Continuous color scale for plot with many lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data set where I want to plot many lines in a single plot. the lines represent events that are ordered and I would like to use the color scale to represent that order. If I do this, I get

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(100)
c(1:10) %>% set_names(seq_along(.)) %>% 
  map(~rnorm(50, 0, 1)) %>% map(cumsum) %>% 
  imap(~tibble(y=.x, color=as.integer(.y))) %>% 
  map(mutate, x=row_number()) %>% 
  reduce(union_all) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=color))+ geom_line()
```

[image: incorrect plot]

I can solve the issue of the incorrect line by making color a factor

```
set.seed(100)
c(1:10) %>% set_names(seq_along(.)) %>% 
  map(~rnorm(50, 0, 1)) %>% map(cumsum) %>% 
  imap(~tibble(y=.x, color=as.factor(.y))) %>% #this is the only changed line
  map(mutate, x=row_number()) %>% 
  reduce(union_all) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=color))+ geom_line()
```

to get the correct line plot, but now my color scales are discrete and the legend is too. I would like the legend to look like the first example and the plot like the second example. furthermore, in the actual data the events are not uniformly spaced around, so the behavior of the continuous color scale is important because the color conveys distance. I tried `group=color` but that doesn't work. What aesthetic am I missing here that would help me achieve the desired outcome?

[image: better plot]

Comment: Try using `group = color, color = color` in aes.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you! I thought I had tried this but maybe when I did I also changed something else. Either way, it works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(100)
c(1:10) %>% set_names(seq_along(.)) %>% 
  map(~rnorm(50, 0, 1)) %>% map(cumsum) %>% 
  imap(~tibble(y=.x, color=as.integer(.y))) %>%
  map(mutate, x=row_number()) %>% 
  reduce(union_all) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, group=color, color=color))+ geom_line()
```